# Xamarin Forms - Share Screen, can you share a "hyperlink"?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm learning Xamarin Forms.  And specifically, if I want to share a complex link, but have the text be something simple how do you do that?  What I have now is below.

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
{
     Uri = "thelink",
     Title = "title", //ios doesn't use title
     Text = "extra text"
});
```

That obviously just puts in the link and some text.  But I want something more akin to an html hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are asking how to put a hiperlink in Xamarin forms, you can do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353339/13373828), just create a class in the Portable project and then call it from your XAML page, but remember to read the [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios) documentation cause you need to put this in you info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>lyft</string>  
<string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `Label` with **Hyperlinks** , you can have a look at this doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#hyperlinks) .

The text displayed by `Label` and `Span` instances can be turned into hyperlinks, sample code as follow :

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Alternatively, click " />
            <Span Text="here"
                  TextColor="Blue"
                  TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span Text=" to view Xamarin documentation." />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

When the hyperlink is tapped, the `TapGestureRecognizer` will respond by executing the `ICommand` defined by its Command property. In addition, the `URL` specified by the CommandParameter property will be passed to the `ICommand` as a parameter.

The code-behind for the XAML page contains the `TapCommand` implementation:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // Launcher.OpenAsync is provided by Xamarin.Essentials.
    public ICommand TapCommand => new Command<string>(async (url) => await Launcher.OpenAsync(url));

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

In addition , you also can create [a reusable hyperlink class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#creating-a-reusable-hyperlink-class) to make the xaml code more sample .

Comment: It isn't a hyperlink in the "app" itself.  Its the "share" portion that needs to be sent a hyperlink.  ie:  you hit "share" and you select say the default messenger app.  The way it is now, it puts a complex link.  I however want it to say something like "Bob's Link" and you can click on it.

Comment: @user3394319 Okey , got it .I will check that , if have solution will share here later .

Comment: @user3394319 You also can share a sample image to show the effect wants , that will be helpful .